# How can I define a variable in FOREACH clause in neo4j, How to find the number of common properties for two nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

As the title suggests, I have a problem of defining and storing variable in neo4j and below is my code:

```
// 6. Display a list of pairs of restaurants having more than three features in common.
MATCH(p1:Place), (p2:Place)
WHERE p1.placeId <> p2.placeId
WITH count = 0
FOREACH(ignoreMe in CASE 
    WHEN
    p1.property1 = p2.property1 THEN [1] 
    WHEN
    p1.property2 = p2.property2 THEN [1]
    WHEN
    ...//omit for university academic requirement
    ELSE []    
    END |
    count = count + 1
)
FOREACH(ignoreMe in CASE 
    WHEN
    count > 3 THEN [1]
    ELSE []    
    END |
    RETURN p1,p2
)
```

I want to find pair of places which have over 3 features in common. When I run this code, the problem occurs because inside foreach I cannot find the variable count. Is there any alternative solution to this? Or is there more efficient way to find the common features for two nodes? Any suggestion is appreciated.
[image: error screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [REDUCE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/list/#functions-reduce) instead of [FOREACH](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/foreach/).

For example:

```
MATCH(p1:Place), (p2:Place)
WHERE p1.placeId < p2.placeId
WITH
  p1, p2,
  REDUCE(
    s = 0,
    k IN [
      'isFranchise', 'parkingArrangements', 'placeAccessibility',
      'placeAlcohol', 'placeArea', 'placeDressCode', 'placeOtherServices',
      'placePrice', 'placeSmoking'] |
    CASE WHEN p1[k] = p2[k] THEN s + 1 ELSE s END
    ) AS count
WHERE count > 3
RETURN p1, p2
```

The `p1.placeId < p2.placeId` test uses the `<` operator instead of `<>`, to avoid evaluating the same pair of nodes twice (in reverse order).

*NOTE: The `MATCH` clause causes a cartesian product with O(N^2) complexity, so this is an expensive query.*

Comment: This is absolutely right and exactly what I want. How do you come up with this solution? I mean how do you convert the logic in ur mind into this neo4j language which is not even complete in terms of programing language

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not the FOREACH, but because the `count` variable is initialized wrongly before :

```
MATCH(p1:Place), (p2:Place)
WHERE p1.placeId <> p2.placeId
WITH count = 0
...
```

should become

```
MATCH(p1:Place), (p2:Place)
WHERE p1.placeId <> p2.placeId
WITH p1, p2, 0 AS count
...
```

Comment: It still does not work and the same error(shown in the above image) pops up. I understand the error is actually that I cannot use count = count+1. I also try set count = count + 1 but set can only be used for nodes.